# How to toggle a background image sprite with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, sprite

I know that their had been a similar post on this here http://bit.ly/wz7kyq but I could not get any of the solutions to work in my case.

I have div with a class "menu-button" that needs toggle a class of "expanded" on and off in order to move the sprite.

right now I have

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    });

    $('.menu-button').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('expanded'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        }
    })
```

However, this does not seem to do anything. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you code contradict itself:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded'); // toggles the "expanded" class
    });

    $('.menu-button').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('expanded'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('expanded'); // reverts the toggle change above
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('expanded'); // reverts the toggle change above
        }
    })
```

Why are you doing the same toggle twice?! That should be enough:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded'); // toggles the "expanded" class
});
```

Comment: Wow Thanks I knew had to be something i was overlooking not sure why they did it in the example i got it from.